# Improving custom models for Watson programmatically

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-knowledge-studio

Is there any way to programmatically load documents into WKS (Watson Knowledge Studio) create an annotation set and task and annotate the document programmatically?
Having that may allow improving custom models from external apps that may prompt users to identify if the NLP analysis of some text was correct or not  for their domain context.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, WKS currently does not provide any APIs that external apps can use.